# file_get_contents can find var directory

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am working on magento 2.4.3. I'm attaching a file in an email from the observer. the file is in the var folder. but file_get_contents(/var/orderexp/firstexport.csv) gives the error
failed to open stream: No such file or directory.
How can i give path to var directory? I am working on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Is the file in the Magento var folder or server var folder? The code above will look in the server var folder.

Comment: Magento var folder

Comment: You will need to figure out your server root. Try something like file_get_contents(./var/orderexp/firstexport.csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
public  function __construct(
   \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
   \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $driverFile,
   LoggerInterface $logger)
{
   $this->directoryList =$directoryList;
   $this->driverFile = $driverFile;
   $this->logger = $logger;
}

   public function getFileContents() {
   $paths = [];
   try {
       $path = $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR). 'orderexp/firstexport.csv';
       //read just that single directory
       $contents =  $this->driverFile->fileGetContents($path);
   } catch (FileSystemException $e) {
       $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
   }

   return $contents;
}
```